# How did Naruto elude the Ninja chasing him at the start of Episode 1?

Tags: naruto

Everyone who has watched Naruto knows that Naruto isn't good at clone jutsu. However, there's a part which confuses me: how did he elude those 2 guys chasing him after he steals that forbidden scroll in the first episode?

In the anime, from 1:40 to 1:50, it showed the same wall where Naruto passed by and followed by 2 guys. Then, 1-2 secs later Naruto was revealed hiding behind the wallpaper. How did he do that? He couldn't have used a transformation jutsu; if he did he could just stay in the transform jutsu. He shouldn't be faster than Chuunin or Jounin, but from 1:41-1:45 it showed them chasing him at the same speed (Although, if they have higher speed than Naruto, they would have caught him).

Comment: If you watch Naruto looking for plot consistency and a compelling storyline you're going to have a bad time, IMHO. Naruto and friends consistently face off against much more skilled and experienced foes and come out ahead by the skin of their teeth every. single. time.

Comment: The rest of the episodes are fine, it was just the first episode I'm curious..

Comment: Quite possibly he has mastered Kage Bunshin no Jutsu at that time. Which also explains why the chasing ninja didn't notice that it was a bunshin.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, he was vandalizing around the town when the two guys were chasing him. He steals the scroll later on. And it wasn't the transformation jutsu either. Just a simple trick with the wall paper. Now don't ask me where did he get that wall paper.

As for speed, even if he is a rookie, he is still a ninja and the other two didn't seem to be exceptionally skilled either. If it's someone like Kakashi, clearly he didn't have a chance.

Answer (score 0):

I figured the ninja didn't want to hurt him by physically detaining him, a chuunin should have more stamina than a normal genin, not that Naruto is normal mind you. They were probably waiting for him to tire out to bring him in with the least injury.

The bunshin part is what confuses me. You could play the devil's advocate and say he turned a corner, created a bunshin, and hid. The issue is he can't create stable bunshins.

Answer (score 0):

The user controls the reflection of light around their body using chakra, causing their form, shadow, and even breathing to become invisible to the unaided eye. Because they perfectly blend in with their surroundings, the user can sneak up behind an enemy without being noticed.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.